# Present perfect or past perfect in this case

Tags: past-tense

> The songs were never released and where made before the band recorded their album "Strange Obsession"... They **have been unheard** for many years until they were recently discovered by Teenadelics Records.

Why present perfect here? I think it should be past perfect  had been unheard because at the time of speaking it belongs to the past .

Comment: I agree that past perfect makes more sense. The "being unheard" ended **recently** which is only a stone's throw from **now**, so there is some justification for using present perfect.

Comment: Can you supply a link to this text? Or is this something you wrote?

Comment: where ==> were (I would fix it but single answer edits are not permitted!)

Comment: it is in fact a note on a back of a record sleeve here is the full text                                               These two two songs were taken from an early recording session at RAK studios. The studios were founded by Mickey Most on 1976 and Protex arrived at the studios in the early summer of 1979 full of gusto having just left school in Belfast and having relocated to London.Of course it is were made

Answer (score 1):

They were unheard of until recently. But at the time of speaking, the situation has changed. Therefore, it should be in past-perfect form.